# How to format output from Beautiful Soup and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I retrieve economic data from a website using the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.findAll('tr',{'class':['fxst-tr-event', 'fxst-oddRow', 'fxit-eventrow', 'fxst-evenRow', 'fxs_cal_nextEvent']}):
    event = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-title'}).text
    currency = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-name'}).text
    actual = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-actual'}).text
    forecast = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-consensus'}).text
    previous = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxst-td-previous fxit-previous'}).text
    time = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
    volatility = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-vol-c fxit-event-info-desktop'}).span['title']

    print(u'\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}').format(time, currency, event, volatility)
```

The output from the print statement is as follows:

```
23:30   
AUD                                     
AiG Performance of Construction Index (Jul)
    Moderate volatility expected
    23:50   
JPY                                     
JP Foreign Reserves (Jul)
    Low volatility expected
    24h 
CAD                                     
August Civic Holiday
    No volatility expected
    01:30   
AUD                                     
ANZ Job Advertisements (Jun)
    Low volatility expected
    n/a 
CNY                                     
Foreign Exchange Reserves (MoM) (Jul)
    Low volatility expected
    05:00   
JPY                                     
Coincident Index (Jun)Preliminar
    Moderate volatility expected
    05:00
```

Is it possible to format this output such that it **prints in line**, as follows?

```
    23:30   AUD   AiG Performance of Construction Index (Jul)   Moderate volatility expected
    23:50   JPY   JP Foreign Reserves (Jul)                     Low volatility expected
    24h     CAD   August Civic Holiday                          No volatility expected
    01:30   AUD   ANZ Job Advertisements (Jun)                  Low volatility expected
    n/a     CNY   Foreign Exchange Reserves (MoM) (Jul)         Low volatility expected
    05:00   JPY   Coincident Index (Jun)Preliminary             Moderate volatility expected
```

The ultimate goal is to cut this output and paste it into an Excel file.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe try stripping newlines?

Comment: so you want like this..?

Comment: print('somethins', end='') # default end is \n

Comment: Yes, but there are newlines in the middle, not just at the end

Comment: why are you using Selenium to fetch the page, rather than just a quick `url.get()`?  seems unnecessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try stripping newlines like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.fxstreet.com/economic-calendar'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for tr in soup.findAll('tr',{'class':['fxst-tr-event', 'fxst-oddRow', 'fxit-eventrow', 'fxst-evenRow', 'fxs_cal_nextEvent']}):
    event = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-title'}).text
    currency = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-name'}).text
    actual = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-actual'}).text
    forecast = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-consensus'}).text
    previous = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxst-td-previous fxit-previous'}).text
    time = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
    volatility = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-vol-c fxit-event-info-desktop'}).span['title']

    print(u'\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}').format(time.strip(), currency.strip(), event.strip(), volatility.strip())
```

This way each string won't have newlines.

Comment: `.strip()` instead of `.strip('\n')` does the same! :)

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answer, since you mentioned that the "the ultimate goal is to cut this output and paste it into an Excel file" you also might be interested in generating a `.csv` from the data, so it could be easily exported to Excel, instead of copy-pasting, after `import csv` you'd  need to change your loop to:

```
with open("data.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    for tr in soup.findAll('tr',{'class':['fxst-tr-event', 'fxst-oddRow', 'fxit-eventrow', 'fxst-evenRow', 'fxs_cal_nextEvent']}):
        event = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-title'}).text
        currency = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-event-name'}).text
        actual = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-actual'}).text
        forecast = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-consensus'}).text
        previous = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxst-td-previous fxit-previous'}).text
        time = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-time fxs_event_time'}).text
        volatility = tr.find('div', {'class': 'fxit-eventInfo-vol-c fxit-event-info-desktop'}).span['title']

        line = [time.strip(),currency.strip(),event.strip(),volatility.strip()]
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(line)
        print(line)
```

Comment: You probably wanna move the creation af the csv.writer object up before the 'for tr'-loop...